# How can I force yui menu appear above slick grid

Tags: css, jquery-ui, yui, slickgrid

I am using YUI Menu with JQuery Slickgrid & JQuery Skin !!! (Yes I know)

I'm having the following problem

[image]

The menu is blending into the grid.  What css should I change to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use z-index to keep your div on top of another.

```
z-index: 5;
```

Comment: I did the opposite, Setting z-index of grid to 0.  Worked perfectly thank you, so simple once you know how.